# How to get ul inside an li

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="cate-item"> 
<button class="cate-label" >item 1 </button>
    <ul class="sub-categ">
    <li> sub item 1</li>
    <li> sub item 2</li>
    <li> sub item 3</li>
    <li> sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="cate-item"> 
<button class="cate-label" >item 2 </button>
<ul class="sub-categ">
    <li> sub item 1</li>
    <li> sub item 2</li>
    <li> sub item 3</li>
    <li> sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This li item is generated dynamically I want to toggle li on the cate-label button click. for that, I did the following code

```
  $(document).on("click", "#categoryList > li .cate-label", function () {
      var currentItem = $(this).closest("li");
      ItemToHide = $("#categoryList > li").not(currentItem);
        ItemToHide.removeClass("active-item");
    ItemToHide.find(".sub-cate").hide();
      currentItem.toggleClass("active-item");
     
     
     }
     
     );
```

when I try to hide item using ItemToHide.find(".sub-cate").hide(); it didn't hide anything . I tried to find the length of the item using ItemToHide.find(".sub-cate").length but it returned 0.

Comment: You are looking for the wrong selector, is `.sub-categ` not `.sub-cate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower your event handling to something closer. I wrapped everything in a `<menu>` tag and registered the click event to it instead of `document`. It doesn't make much of a difference performance wise but I suggest it because it's looks as if your perspective is skewed if dealing with a larger view of the DOM and you'll be error prone:

```
var currentItem = $(this).closest("li");
      ItemToHide = $("#categoryList > li").not(currentItem);
        ItemToHide.removeClass("active-item");
    ItemToHide.find(".sub-cate").hide();
      currentItem.toggleClass("active-item");
```

That nightmare is now:

```
$(this).next('.sub-categ').toggle('ease-out');
```

```js
$('menu').on("click", ".cate-label", toggleList);

function toggleList(e) {
  $(this).next('.sub-categ').toggle('ease-out');
};
```

```html
<menu>
  <li class="cate-item">
    <button class="cate-label">item 1 </button>
    <ul class="sub-categ">
      <li> sub item 1</li>
      <li> sub item 2</li>
      <li> sub item 3</li>
      <li> sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="cate-item">
    <button class="cate-label">item 2 </button>
    <ul class="sub-categ">
      <li> sub item 1</li>
      <li> sub item 2</li>
      <li> sub item 3</li>
      <li> sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</menu>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if the li items are dynamically populated is it possible to attach click listeners with out document?

Comment: I have the click event registered to `<menu>` which is the parent of all `<li>` , so as long as the event is bound to an ancestor element. You don't have to worry whether a tag is dynamically added or how many tags there are. This technique is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

Comment: You can bind/attach to * any static* parent.  As long as `menu` chosen above isn't also created dynamically, then this is ideal.   People tend to use `document` simply because you can be sure it exists.

Comment: Yeah, OP made a simple typo and was chaining everything together trying to traverse to/from `document` which is the only reason I suggested a closer ancestor .

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the name of the class is not correct. Should be `'sub-cate'`, not `'sub-categ'`.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#categoryList > li .cate-label", function () {
                  var currentItem = $(this).closest("li");
                  ItemToHide = $("#categoryList > li").not(currentItem);
                  ItemToHide.removeClass("active-item");
                  ItemToHide.find(".sub-cate").hide();
                  currentItem.toggleClass("active-item");
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="categoryList">
  <li class="cate-item"> 
    <button class="cate-label" >item 1 </button>
    <ul class="sub-cate"><!--rename the class name-->
      <li> sub item 1</li>
      <li> sub item 2</li>
      <li> sub item 3</li>
      <li> sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="cate-item"> 
    <button class="cate-label" >item 2 </button>
    <ul class="sub-cate"><!--rename the class name-->
      <li> sub item 1</li>
      <li> sub item 2</li>
      <li> sub item 3</li>
      <li> sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```